# Añadir package ExtJs

Tags: extjs

He descargado un nuevo package premium para ExtJs 6.7.0 pero no se como añadirlo a mi aplicación para que desde view hacer el 'extend:Ext.calendar.panel.Panel' pueda utilizarlo.

El package ya lo he insertado en la Sdk de la versión de Sencha.

Error consola: http://ip/app/Ext/calendar/panel/Panel.js ==> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Pd. Aprendiendo Sencha....

Answer (score 1):

Tenés varias formas de hacerlo, una es agregando la librería en el app.json de tu proyecto:

```
"requires": ["exporter", "calendar", "*nombre_librería*"],
```

Otra es subir el sdk al webserver u referenciarlo desde el index.html, por lo general son archivos del tipo *paquete*-debug.js que se encuentran dentro del sdk en la carpeta *paquete*/build/classic/resources/*nombre_paquete*-debug.js, ejemplo:

No olvides agregar las hojas de estilo, ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="url_al_sdk_addons/packages/exporter/build/classic/resources/exporter-all-debug.css">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias ;-)
La solución fue agregar las hojas de estilo como indicaste y el nombre_paquete-debug.js como **Ext.Loader.loadScript('nombre_paquete-debug.js')** dentro del **app.js.**